# video background break hash linking

Tags: css, html5-video

I have basic `video` background. When i click on link, that points to id of element inside block with video background something strange happen: target block is like "scrolling" inside block.

Expected behaviour: browser scroll user to target element, without breaking paddings.

Here is a simplified version (click on the link). Tested in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) on Mac OSX.

```css
.tile-block {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tile-block__wrap {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 6%;
}
#target-block {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.video-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-block">
  <div class="tile-block__wrap">
    <div id="target-block">Something here</div>
  </div>

  <video class="video-background">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<a href="#target-block">Click here</a>
```

What is wrong with it? Same styles applied to plain `div` works as expected.

```css
.tile-block {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tile-block__wrap {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 6%;
}
#target-block {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.video-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-block">
  <div class="tile-block__wrap">
    <div id="target-block">Something here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="video-background">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#target-block">Click here</a>
```